# Check if one range is a subrange of another range in a nice, STL-ish way

Tags: c++, stl, c++11

Suppose we have two ranges `r1 = [first1, last1)` and `r2 = [first2, last2)`

Let's say that `r2` is a ***subrange*** of `r1` iff there exists such `i>=0` that

1. `[first1 + i, first1 + i + last2 - first2)` is a valid range
2. for all j in `[0, last2 - first2)` the following holds:

   ```
   *(first1 + i + j) == *(first2 + j)
   ```

A nested loop can easily determine if `r2` is a subrange of `r1`, or even one loop with a nested call to `std::equal` template. Is there a more STL-ish, concise way to express the same idea in C++? C++0x solutions are welcome, too. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `std::search` is what you're looking for. From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/search/ [`std::search`] "Searches the range [first1,last1) for the first occurrence of the sequence defined by [first2,last2), and returns an iterator to its first element."

Comment: Yup, that's it :) How did I forget that function?!

Comment: are you sure you want this function ?
it works such that, for every iterator j in the range [first2, last2), *(i + (j - first2)) == *j.
if you just want to compare iterators this is overkill: comparing every elements may cost you some cpu cycles
you want to have a look at std::distance().

Comment: @ppi the original question specifically shows dereferencing the iterators.

Comment: sure, my point was just that this conditions illustrated by deferencing the iterators, holds every time when dealing with sub-ranges within the same container like vectors, hence the shortcut with distance in this *specific* case :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is yo illustrate my previous comment:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

template<class MyIterator>
bool is_subrange(const MyIterator& first1, const MyIterator& last1, const MyIterator& first2, const MyIterator& last2)
{
   return std::distance(first1, first2) >=0 && std::distance(last2, last1) >= 0;
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> v;
   for (int i=0; i < 100; ++i)
      v.push_back(i);
   std::cout << std::distance(v.begin(), v.end()) << std::endl;
   std::cout << std::distance(v.end(), ++v.begin()) << std::endl;
   std::cout << is_subrange(v.begin(), v.end(), ++v.begin(), --v.end()) << std::endl;
   std::cout << is_subrange(++v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), --v.end()) << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

This avoids comparing each element when dealing with subranges inside the same simple containers like vectors.

Of course the function is_subrange() is very simple and gets more complicated with lists as they are doubly linked and hence the distance can never be negative e.g. std::distance(l.begin(), l.end()) == 1 and std::distance(l.end(), l.begin()) == 1 are possible.
Ranges as [100,0] and [20,4] are also not handled by this simple sample, but it is feasible.

Anyway, std::search() will do the job as previously posted by Mark-b

cheers,